# How to identify which components are holding space in the postgres server

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a PG server which occupies 2 TB space. However on checking the sum of size of each table, it adds up only to 100 GB.
What is taking up space and how can I free it ?

Comment: How did you check the sum of each table?  There are different ways that count different things (index, toast, etc.)

Comment: Use filesystem tools to check the subdirectories of the data directory.  `du -sh $PGDATA| sort -h` is my favorite.

Comment: @jjanes After reading your comment, I included other things in the query and now I know that toast size of one table is around 1.8 TB
Thanks for giving me a direction.